# .htaccess for static php file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I had to add a PHP file within a Wordpress installation. I have created a subfolder and the file works fine, but I need to make it "pretty" according to Wordpress permalinks style.
In few words:
`https://example.com/php/partners.php`
must become `https://example.com/our-partners/`

How can I do it? Where should I place the .htaccess file? In the root as it is now or will I need another one in "php" folder?

Thank you!!!
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way make wordpress template in theme.

Put below code at the top of the php file in comments

```
<?php /* Template Name: logicdigger */ ?>
```

Then move your file in to your theme.

Go to add page and create new page then select template from right side of your screen. THAT'S ALL

Complete article [here](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/creating-custom-page-template-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Sounds like a cool idea. Does it work if I add it inside my child theme? otherwise I risk to have it deleted at every update.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Or template not showing in meta box?

Answer (score 1):

You will edit the existing `.htaccess` file in the root. Something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?our-partners/?$ /php/partners.php
```

Requests to `/our-partners` and `/our-partners/` (with or without trailing slash) will point to `/php/partners.php`. This also allows for query params in the URL if needed: `/our-partners?foo=bar`

This requires [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to be enabled in apache. The docs for RewriteRule can be [found here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html)

Comment: Hi Brett! Thank you, but it gives me "page not found". mod_rewrite is on as it is being used by wordpress plugins, maybe it could be a conflict?

Comment: Try moving this rule right to the top of your `.htaccess` file

Comment: Also could you add the contents of your existing `.htaccess` file to the question?

Comment: # Leverage Browser Caching by SG-Optimizer


RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?our-partners /php/partners.php



<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 2 months"
  # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"
  # Data interchange
    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"

Comment: There is more, but I do not have enough space for the whole text!

Comment: "add the contents of your existing `.htaccess` file **to the question**" - you can _edit_ your question to add formatted code blocks of "unlimited" size.